# How do I convert an Excel or similar (not just a plain text file) to bytes or binary then back again

Tags: python, excel, file, tkinter

I have written an encryption program that I want to be able to encrypt Excel files with and then decrypt them and output a final Excel file. I have decided to read the whole file then encrypt it as it would be easier than reading each cell from the Excel file.

So far I have been able to read the file and convert it to bytes but cannot figure out how to turn it back into an Excel file.

```
root = Tk()
root.withdraw()

file = filedialog.askopenfile(initialdir="C:")##Creates a file dialog to pick a file
tempFile=open(file.name,encoding="Latin-1")##Encodes it with Latin-1 so all 256 bytes can be read
file.close()

data=tempFile.read()
tempFile.close()

newFile=open("testfile","w",encoding="cp1252")##Creates a new file with cp1252 encoding as that is what Excel uses

newFile.write(data)
newFile.close() ##Currently it just fills the Excel file with a whole bunch of random characters
```

Edit:

To be more concise, what I want to do is take the data from an Excel file with anything in it, encrypt it, decrypt it and then write it back into a new Excel file with all formatting etc intact. Is there a way to do the reading and writing of the whole file?

Comment: Please do not write your own encryption. Encryption is one of the hardest things to make properly and should only be used if it is: 1) Open source, 2) Peer revived, 3) Compiles with integrity, confidentiality, and availability. There are tons of open source, peer reviewed, CIA model encryption libraries for Python. Look at something like this: https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/06/25/aes-encryption-of-files-in-python-with-pycrypto instead of writing your own

Comment: Please, _do_ write your own encryption schemes. Suggesting not to do that is like suggesting not to prove any mathematical law by yourself. _Do_ write your encryption schemes but just don't put them on the field unless it is publicly verified to have no weaknesses.

Comment: `Excel` file is not text file so `encoding` make no sense - it only destroys data. As I know current excel format is `zip` file with `xml` file inside (and with other files like `jpg` and subfolders)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? If you just load it as binary, keep it as bytes and then write it as binary you won't have any issue.

Comment: to read Excel as binary you can open with binary mode `open(... , 'rb')`

Comment: Ok thanks for the comments, I am trying to take the data out of the Excel file, encrypt it, decrypt it and then put it back in a new Excel file, I could use a library like xlsxwriter to read data from the individual cells but I want this to work on any Excel file not just one of a specific format so I don't think this will work. Is there a way to do this easily?

Comment: @Oscar What do you mean by any excel file?

Comment: @Nae To start with just one with text in any of the cells but hopefully, it would be able to do charts and graphs etc.., is that what you meant?

Comment: @Oscar No, I thought you meant multiple file formats.

Comment: Also @StevenByrne I am not planning on actually using this to hide secret government data, it is just a project I am working on to improve my understanding of cryptography.

Comment: if you want change data inside Excel and still have file which you can open in Microsoft Excel or other program then you have to use tools like `xlsxwriter` because it knows how this file is constructed. It knows where is text and where are other information which you shouldn't change because you get corrupted file. Excel file can be very complex.

Comment: @furas ok thanks I will look into this more now that I know it is better to do it that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer to my problem, @furas your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48064607/how-do-i-convert-an-excel-or-similar-not-just-a-plain-text-file-to-bytes-or-bi/48067240#comment83103461_48064607) is what I needed to do:

```
selectedFile = filedialog.askopenfile(initialdir="C:")
tempFile=open(selectedFile.name,mode="rb")
data=tempFile.read()

newFile=open("test.xlsx",mode="wb")
newFile.write(data)
```

This creates the exact same file as the original one.